# Projective direct image and commutation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let us denote by $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a projective map between two varieties, and $i:Z\rightarrow X$ an open inclusion.

Is it correct to write :

$$f_*(Im(i_!\mathscr{F}\rightarrow i_* \mathscr{F})=Im(f_* i_!\mathscr{F}\rightarrow f_* i_* \mathscr{F})$$

Thank you. Jean.

Comment: Yes. The map $i_!\mathcal{F}\to i_*\mathcal{F}$ should be injective, so you can simplify the left side to $f_*i_!\mathcal{F}$. Now use left exactness of $f_*$ to see that you get the same thing on the right.