# Proper direct image and minimal extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let us denote by $i:U\rightarrow X$ an open inclusion and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $U$.

Is the map $i_!\mathcal{F} \rightarrow i_*\mathcal{F}$ always injective ?

I ask this question because it seemed to me that we define the minimal extension $i_{!*}\mathcal{F}$ as the image of $i_!\mathcal{F} \rightarrow i_*\mathcal{F}$, and if we want to get an interesting extension (not the extension by zero), it would be better not to have $i_{!*}\mathcal{F} \simeq i_{!}\mathcal{F}$.

Probably I'm confuse and I don't see an obvious thing, but an answer of Donu Arapura [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304773/projective-direct-image-and-commutation), concerning a question of commutation I had, makes me doubt.

Thank you. Jean.

Comment: OK, since you're talking about *minimal extensions*, it seems to me that you're really dealing with *perverse sheaves*, but I'm just guessing. Perverse sheaves aren't actually sheaves, and map you write down need not be injective.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I have to be careful with perverse sheaves (I'm not very familiar with this category actually).

Comment: But, does the relation of the other post remain true for perverse sheaves ? (or, more understable for me, in terms of $\mathscr{D}$-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s what your misunderstanding: $i_{!*}\mathcal F$ is the image of $i_!\mathcal F \to i_* \mathcal F$ *in the category of perverse sheaves*. It’s instructive to look at the case $U=\Bbb C^*$ and $X=\Bbb C$. Try showing that the cone of $$i_! \Bbb C_U[1] \to i_* \Bbb C_U[1]$$ is not perverse (in the middle perversity). Note that I’m assuming that you’re using $i_*$ for the derived direct image functor.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example, it is now perfectly clear.