# Commutation and minimal extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This question follows these two : [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304773/projective-direct-image-and-commutation) and [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307053/proper-direct-image-and-minimal-extension). As far as it is specific, I ask it here.

Let us denote by $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a projective map between two varieties, $i:U\rightarrow X$ an open inclusion and $M$ a (holonomic regular) $\mathscr{D}$-module.

Is it correct to write :

$$f_* i_{!*}M = Im(f_* i_!M \rightarrow f_* i_* M)$$

(and should we assume that $f_* i_!M$ and $f_* i_* M$ are $\mathscr{D}$-modules and not complexes ?)

According to [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304773/projective-direct-image-and-commutation) (thanks to Donu Arapura), this property is true for coherent sheaves but in this case the map $i_! \mathscr{F} \rightarrow i_* \mathscr{F}$ is injective.

Thank you. Jean.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $f_*$ (and $f_!$) is pushforward (with compact support) in the category of $\mathcal{D}$-modules.

If $f_* i_! M$ and $f_* i_* M$ are $\mathcal{D}_Y$-modules and $f$ projective, then the map $f_* i_! M \rightarrow f_* i_* M$ is well defined in the category of $\mathcal{D}_Y$-modules because it corresponds to the map $(f \circ i)_! M \rightarrow (f \circ i)_* M$.

Now it's probably possible to use left-exactness of $f_*$ to conclude (but I don't see exactly why, maybe other people can precise my answer on this point).